# set/getAttribute removing whitespace?

Tags: jsp

I'm trying to display a string on my JSP using `getAttribute`, but when it displays the text, it is smashed together with no spacing in between. Before displaying it, I print the string to verify it on the console and it displays correctly there.

So for example it prints "xxx xx xxxx xx" correctly, but when I go through `setAttribute`, then `getAttribute`, and then display it in a table, it shows up as "xxxxxxxxxxx". Why has the whitespace been removed?

Here is the line in question:

```
<table border="0">
  <tr>                  
    <td width="500" title="resultsLists">
      <%=session.getAttribute("hotBackUpList")%>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is assembly of hotBackUpList

```
try { 
    conn = ConnectionPoolSelector.getConnection(); 
    dbmsOutput = new DbmsOutput( conn ); 
    dbmsOutput.enable( 1000000 ); 
    cstmt = conn.prepareCall("begin " + "pkg_util_backup.sp_util_hotbackup    (); "          + "end;");   
    cstmt.executeQuery(); 

    hotBackUpList = dbmsOutput.show().toString();
    return hotBackUpList;
```

DBMSOutput

```
public String show() throws SQLException
{
     String dmsResult = null;

     int               done = 0;

    show_stmt.registerOutParameter( 2, java.sql.Types.INTEGER );
    show_stmt.registerOutParameter( 3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR );

    for(;;)
    {    
        show_stmt.setInt( 1, 32000 );
        show_stmt.executeUpdate();
        dmsResult = show_stmt.getString(3);
        //System.out.print( show_stmt.getString(3) );
        //dmsResult = show_stmt.getString(3).toString();
        if ( (done = show_stmt.getInt(2)) == 1 ) break;

    }


    return dmsResult;
}
```

Java Output

%/used       %/total  date          name

---

0% ( 0%)    0% ( 0%)  Jul 19 14:56  ppidev_snap_hot_user_2013-07-191456 
  0% ( 0%)    0% ( 0%)  Jul 19 09:59  ppidev_snap_hot_user_2013-07-190959 
  0% ( 0%)    0% ( 0%)  Jul 18 23:22  ppidev-cold_RECENT 
  0% ( 0%)    0% ( 0%)  Jul 18 16:32  ppidev_snap_hot_user_2013-07-181632 
  0% ( 0%)    0% ( 0%)  Jul 18 08:34  ppidev_snap_hot_user_2013-07-180834 
  0% ( 0%)    0% ( 0%)  Jul 17 23:21  ppidev-cold_071713-2320

HTML Output
%/used %/total date name ---------- ---------- ------------ -------- 0% ( 0%) 0% ( 0%) Jul 19 14:56 ppidev_snap_hot_user_2013-07-191456 0% ( 0%) 0% ( 0%) Jul 19 09:59 ppidev_snap_hot_user_2013-07-190959 0% ( 0%) 0% ( 0%) Jul 18 23:22 ppidev-cold_RECENT 0% ( 0%) 0% ( 0%) Jul 18 16:32 ppidev_snap_hot_user_2013-07-181632 0% ( 0%) 0% ( 0%) Jul 18 08:34 ppidev_snap_hot_user_2013-07-180834 0% ( 0%) 0% ( 0%) Jul 17 23:21 ppidev-cold_071713-2320 0% ( 0%) 0% ( 0%) Jul 17 17:22 ppidev_snap_hot_user_2013-07-171722 0% ( 0%) 0% ( 0%) Jul 17 17:18 ppidev_snap_hot_user_2013-07-171718 0% ( 0%) 0% ( 0%) Jul 17 16:57 ppidev_snap_hot_user_2013-07-171657 0% ( 0%) 0% ( 0%) Jul 17 16:40 ppidev_snap_hot_user_2013-07-171640 0% ( 0%) 0% ( 0%) Jul 17 16:24 ppidev_snap_hot_user_2013-07-171624 0% ( 0%) 0% ( 0%) Jul 17 15:47 ppidev_snap_hot_user_2013-07-171547 0% ( 0%) 0% ( 0%) Jul 17 15:42 ppidev_snap_hot_user_2013-07-171542 0% ( 0%) 0% ( 0%) Jul 17 13:43 ppidev_snap_hot_user_2013-07-171342 0% ( 0%) 0% ( 0%) Jul 17 09:49

Thanks!

Comment: what is the type of hotBackUpList?

Comment: hotBackUpList is a String type

Comment: Your problem is not with getting the attribute, it is when hotBackUpList is being formulated. Can you show the code for the same?

Comment: This is my dataaccess method where i execute an SQL statement that returns the string I want from a stored procedure. I think call a method for DBMS output.  try {
   conn = ConnectionPoolSelector.getConnection();
   dbmsOutput = new DbmsOutput( conn ); 
      dbmsOutput.enable( 1000000 );
 
         cstmt = conn.prepareCall("begin " +
                 "pkg_util_backup.sp_util_hotbackup(); " +
                 "end;");         
         
         cstmt.executeQuery();

         hotBackUpList = dbmsOutput.show().toString();

Comment: the output of dbmsOutput is causing string to attach together.

Comment: Show us the relevant part of the generated HTML. What you get when right-clicking in the browser and selecting "view page source".

Comment: ok i will look at dbmsOutput. i thought it wouldnt be that because when i print it from there it looks correct, i must be overlooking something. Thank you so much for your help! You pointed me in right direction!

Comment: Oh, you don't print it from Java? Then do so and also show this output.

Comment: I did print from Java, it printed correctly

Comment: i can't get the editor to show it correctly, but on Java side it looks correct

Comment: The either you're not printing the same thing in both cases, or you have some code changing its value somewhere in the middle.

Comment: i did a viewsource on the page, and the correct alignment for the string was viewable there! but why would it not show correctly in runtime? maybe my table isnt the correct size?

Comment: Then it's a font, CSS or screen problem. Or some Javascript transforming the value.